# Django and django rest framework saving profile information

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

How is possible to save profile information as I am using django rest api to login a user and the response which I am getting is with the help of requests library .what I want is to save the response and show in profile page .How can I achieve this in django?should I use cookies or session for this.

Answer (score 0):

when you login , it will auto fetch your login details and reference it with any new change made to profile.
if any save(update in profile) made it will just save information by accepting response .

Please find below code snipped from my code

[image]

Comment: I am using django rest api for login and calling requests from another django view like
request.get(api,params={key:value}) after this call i am getting some response i have to save that response and show profile information from view like yours.
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/